# Docker does not build and run first service when there are two services in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`docker-compose up -d` works fine when I have only the postgres service in the docker-compose.yml code below. But once I add the python service, the postgres container is never run even though its image is built. `docker container ls -a` shows that it does not exist.

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.postgres
    restart: always
    container_name: test_postgres
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"

  # Once this python service is added, the postgres does not run.
  python:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.python
    restart: on-failure:10
    container_name: test_python
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
```

I haven't been able to find clear information on why this should be. Some solutions mention that version 3 doesn't use `depends_on` anymore. I thought this might be a possible issue so I removed it and added `restart: on-failure:10` but it made no difference.

If I run `docker-compose up -d` with just the postgres service in it first, then add the python service into the same docker-compose.yml file and run it again, both images are built and containers run properly.

Not sure if necessary but here are the Dockerfiles for the services:

Dockerfile.postgres:

```
FROM postgres

WORKDIR /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

ENV POSTGRES_DB test_postgres

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD 1234

COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 5432
```

Dockerfile.python:

```
FROM python:latest

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./backend/ /code

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN python manage.py migrate

RUN python manage.py loaddata customers

EXPOSE 8000

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `docker-compose up` without `-d`? Maybe you can see something wrong in the container logs.

Comment: This might be a timing issue. Docker-compose does not wait for the postgres server to be ready before starting the python service, see [docker-compose doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on).